# Formatting a strange DataFrame a the pythonic way

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with a really strange format, columns are matching/linked two by two.
The first column contains labels and codes associated with the adjacent column values.

Here's what it looks like :

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | letter_1 | Name | letter_2 |
| Title | Choose a letter: | Title | Choose another letter |
| 1 | a | 1 | z |
| 2 | b | 2 | y |
| 3 | c |  |  |
| 4 | d |  |  |

And here's what I need :

| Name | Title | Code | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| letter_1 | Choose a letter: | 1 | a |
| letter_1 | Choose a letter: | 2 | b |
| letter_1 | Choose a letter: | 3 | c |
| letter_1 | Choose a letter: | 4 | d |
| letter_2 | Choose another letter | 1 | z |
| letter_2 | Choose another letter | 2 | y |

I managed to do it with that code:

```
# Init an empty DataFrame
df_format = pd.DataFrame()

# Iterate over the columns, step 2
for i in range(0, len(df.columns), 2):

    # Get the columns names for current col and col+1, since they're linked together
    col_i, col_ii = df.columns[i], df.columns[i]+1

    # Concat codes from col and labels from col+1
    codes = pd.concat([df[col_i].loc[3:], df[col_ii].loc[3:]], axis=1).dropna()

    # Get the "Name", col+1 line 0
    name = df[col_ii].loc[0]
    # Get the title, col+1 line 1
    title = df[col_ii].loc[1]
    codes.loc[:, ['Name', 'Title']] = [name, title]
    codes.columns = ["Code", "Label", "Name", "Title"]
    df_format = pd.concat([df_format, codes])
```

But the question is: is there a more pythonic way to do this ?
I assume it is with pandas but sometimes it kind of break my brain.

Here is the example to use with `pd.DataFrame`

```
[{1: 'Name', 2: 'letter_1', 3: 'Name', 4: 'letter_2'},
 {1: 'Title', 2: 'Choose a letter:', 3: 'Title', 4: 'Choose another letter'},
 {1: 1, 2: 'a', 3: 1, 4: 'z'},
 {1: 2, 2: 'b', 3: 2, 4: 'y'},
 {1: 3, 2: 'c', 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan},
 {1: 4, 2: 'd', 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan}]
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

**EDIT**

This data come from an Excel file with another sheet containing the answers given by some respondents where the columns names are corresponding to letter_1, letter_2, etc.

The sheet I am working on has about 15.000 columns, all ordered the same way, as shown above.

I read it with `pd.read_excel(file, header=None, sheetname="sheet1")`, that's why I do not have easy to read column names (I dropped column 0)

Comment: Where did this data come from? A dataframe is an in-memory construct, not a data format. It's easier to read the source data in a usable way than try to untangle it after the fact

Comment: This data come from an Excel file, I created a reproductible example from it since I am not allowed to use the real data online.

Comment: What does the Excel file look like? One sheet or many? Are there any named regions? You can load multiple sheets into multiple dataframes. You can also specify the column range to import

Comment: Use `usecols` to read only the column pairs you need each time and transform them to the shape you want. You can use `pd.concat` after that to concatenate all dataframes into a single one.